# wordpress - get posts with custom field numeric order and then by date

Tags: wordpress, meta

In a wordpress cms, I need to shows posts based primarily on meta_value_num and then by date order. My query arguments is set according to [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103181/sorting-custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-num-then-by-title#answer-103199). But the posts seem to ignore both the order. Here is the code I am using.

```
function change_order($order,$qry) {
  remove_filter('posts_orderby','alter_order', 1, 2);
  $order = explode(',',$order);
  $order = implode( ' ASC,',$order);
  return $order;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','change_order', 1, 2);

$q = new WP_Query();
$q->query( array(
  'post_type' => 'post', 
  'meta_key' => 'colleges_intown',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',  
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'post_status' => 'publish',
));

while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); echo ' - '.get_the_time('d-m-Y', $q->post->ID);
echo ' - '.get_post_meta($q->post->ID, 'colleges_intown', true) ; 
?>
</h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
```

The code given in the solution seems pretty solid so chances are I made a mistake in the loop, can someone point out what ? Here is what the results look like. Completely ignoring the custom-meta numeric order as well as date.

```
    Cochin     -  22-04-2014  - 2
    Bangalore  -  28-04-2014  - 56
    New Delhi  -  22-04-2014  - 0
    Kolkatta   -  31-05-2014  - 1
    Chennai    -  25-04-2014  - 44
    Hyderabad  -  31-05-2014  - 88
```

Comment: Your `orderby` parameter doesn't have any commas, but your filter does this: `$order = explode(',',$order);`.  Does it work if you do `$order = explode(' ',$order);`?  And your `remove_filter` call seems to have the wrong function name (shouldn't it be `change_order`, not `alter_order`)?

Comment: [Here is the original code](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103181/sorting-custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-num-then-by-title#answer-103199) by an expert and it seems to be working there. However, the suggested changes doesnot work.